# Import CSV files into SQL database in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I've searched similar thread but no luck so far, so I am building a RoR application and I have already create the database, I just want to import the css file into my database, below is the files I have the errors I got:

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170913210926) do
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "tags"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

I also have a rake task file(import.task):

```
require 'csv'
csv_text = File.read('/Path/to/csv/Item.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  item.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

So when I ran rake import.task in terminal I got the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `item' for main:Object
```

Comment: Is `Item` the name of your model? Try `Item.create!` instead of `item.create!`

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge I believe so, I have item.rb file in my models directory.

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge Tried Item still doesn't work, error log is shown below

Comment: is that the full contents of your `import.task` file? It's not formatted correctly for a proper rake file, and without the proper formatting, it won't load your environment. See an example here: https://gist.github.com/barboza/3747123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rake task looks more like a regular ruby script than a rake task. If you want to use rake for this, try something like:

```
require 'csv'

namespace :import do
  desc 'Imports csv data into db'
  task from_csv: :environment do
    csv_text = File.read('/Path/to/csv/Item.csv')
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      Item.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

and invoke it with `rake import:from_csv`

Comment: Thanks your answer works but I do have another problem, my CSV file contains an Id column, so when I tried to import it I got:ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'Id' for Item, any idea how should I handle this?

Comment: What are all the header names, exactly? Immediately I see two things to check for: 1) methods are case sensitive. Either make sure the headers are all lowercased, or lowercase all the keys in ruby before passing the row to Item.create! 2) `id` is usually used as the model's primary key in the db. Depending on your use case, you may not want to insert that field into the db, or you may want to use a different key for it. This is really dependent on your use case though, so I'm not sure what's right for you.

Comment: And here's a snippet to downcase a hash's keys: `def downcase_keys(hash) ; hash.reduce({}) {|accum, (k,v)| accum.merge k.to_s.downcase.to_sym => v} ; end`

Comment: Hi Glyoko, thanks so much for your help, in the csv file first column is Id, I changed it to id and it works, but I'm wondering is there a way to handle this other than manually change the header value, for example ditch the Id column when importing the CSV file

Comment: `row.reject{|k,_| k.to_s == "id"}` will return `row` without the id field.